# View Model, Dependency Properties Confusion

Tags: wpf, view, model, dependencies, properties

I am developing a custom WPF control and confused how to use the dependency property. My view model contains 2 properties:

```
class Customer {
  string Name;
  string ID;
}
```

My custom control is responsible for displaying these fields.

Q1: Do I need to define any dependency properties (eg "Name", "ID") in my custom control?

Q2: I am using ItemsControl to display a list of Customers. How is the Customer object passed to my custom control?   Is it done through the DataContext or do I need to add a "Customer" dependency property in my control and in the xaml, bind "Customer" to "something" (what's that something)?

```
<ItemPresenter>
   <MyCustomControl  Customer="??what should i put here???"/>
</ItemPresender>
```

Comment: Normally you don't create custom controls just to display some data, you rather use [datatemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. Why do you have a custom control? Ordinarily, you would just create a `UserControl` (there is a distinction in WPF between `UserControl` and custom control) and bind properties within your `UserControl` to properties of your view model. For example (let's call this `CustomerView`):

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Q2. Through the `DataContext`. For example, you might have something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CustomerView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Each item generated by the `ItemsControl` will have the related data item set as its `DataContext`. Hence, each `CustomerView` will have the appropriate `Customer` as its `DataContext`.